# Ruby Picture Censoring Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Ruby and would like to learn how to build a gem that allows users to sensor different parts of a photo they upload.  Hence, any tutorials, git repositories, or similar gems would be GREATLY appreciated!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [RMagick](http://rubygems.org/gems/rmagick).

[`blur` method is probably what you are looking for.](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/imageattrs.html#blur)